git rebase removed "cherry picked" commit that wasn't cherry picked
I had a situation where I merged a branch A into main, and then realized that I shouldn't have done it. So I created another branch B that reverted a portion of what I had merged in A, and merged that.
Now I have decided that the original change can finally go out, so I made a branch C that undoes B, getting me close to what I had originally with A (not exactly).
I have not yet merged C. I ran git rebase main before I pushed. I soon realized that the rebase went wrong with the following message:
warning: skipped previously applied commit 6d3c69e8da
hint: use --reapply-cherry-picks to include skipped commits

Basically out of 2 commits in C, one got skipped because it thinks it was cherry-picked. I have a number of questions related to this:

I did NOT use any sort of built-in cherry-picking functionality, so why does it think that it was cherry-picked? I manually copied the file over from a previous branch.
How can I fix this and keep the commit in C? I ran git rebase main --reapply-cherry-picks however all it says is Current branch mybranch is up to date. and does not actually reapply anything.
Why would this functionality be useful, when here it's the opposite of what I want?


Can somebody explain why this got voted down? It isn't exactly an easy thing to google and is a hard thing to understand.

"I had a situation where I merged a branch A into main, and then realized that I shouldn't have done it" Stop right there. At that point, why didn't you / don't you reset main hard back to the commit just before the merge? Now you are cleanly out of this entire mess; the original merge never happened, kaboom.

@matt because it was already merged into the main pipeline at our company and followed by many other commits before I realized

The kind of assumptions that were made about this question are why people get discouraged with StackOverflow.
